# Update content from XMLHTTPRequest every 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

First of all, I would like to say that I'm a student learning programming for around a month, so expect to see many mistakes.

I'm working on a website where I use a chart from the ChartJs library. The data used for this chart is taken through requests to a server.

What I want to do is update the content of the `studenGesamt` variable every 20 seconds. My main idea was using a `setInterval`, but it didn't work. I am thinking that I could make a new request to the server every 20 seconds, but I am kind of lost on how to do that or if it is actually a good idea. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

```js
let serverData;
let studenGesamt;
let date;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://url.com/'; // I have hidden this URL as it is the actual server from my company
http.open("GET", url);
http.setRequestHeader('key', 'sample-key'); // I have hidden this key for the same reason as above
http.send();
const chart = document.getElementById("multie-pie-chart");

// Function that calculates the workdays passed up until today
const workdaysCount = () => [...new Array(new Date().getDate())]
  .reduce((acc, _, monthDay) => {
    const date = new Date()
    date.setDate(1 + monthDay) ![0, 6].includes(date.getDay()) && acc++
      return acc
  }, 0)

http.onload = (e) => {

  // Parsing the JSON file and storing it into a variable (Console.Log() to make sure it works)
  serverData = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
  console.log(serverData);

  // Storing the value of total hours from the database in a variable
  studenGesamt = serverData.abzurechnen.gesamt;

  chartRender(); // Function that calls and renders the chart

  setInterval(dataLoop, 5000); // 5 seconds to be able to test it, will be changed to 20 when finished

};

let dataLoop = () => {
  studenGesamt = serverData.abzurechnen.gesamt;
  console.log('test'); // Logging test to see if it is working
};
```

Comment: Can you include your setInterval solution in the code and tell us if you got any errors?

Comment: @Gerard I have added it now. I'm not sure if it is correct or not. I don't get any errors and the `console.log('Test')` works, logging the word every 5 seconds. I had an error before on the `setInterval` syntax and that's why I was getting an error. As the data in the server has not changed for a while, I don't know if there is any way to find out if the variable is being updated or not.